# How to select rows that start with "<img" with an IF statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have two columns, `Entry` and `text_image`, in a table.  When looping to see all the rows in an array, I can get the results, but I want it to add `/images` to the rows that have text starting with `img`. This is to direct the rows that have "img" (meaning the text within the row) to the correct folder. It might need further explanation to illustrate why but I wont get into it.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result3 )) {
    echo "<div class=\'entry\'>";
    (I want to add an echo "/images" before the rows that start with "img")

    echo $row[\'text_image\'];
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$images = (substr($row['text_image'], 0, 3) == 'img') ? "/images" : "";
echo $images . $row['text_image'];
```

This will check if the first 3 letters of `$row['text_image']` are `img` then set `$images` to `/images` else it will leave it empty. This will update each time within the loop.

Comment: thanks mate, one thing though what would it be for <img, instead of img? do i change that to 0, 4?

Comment: Yep, just change it to `substr($row['text_image'], 0, 4) == '<img'`

Comment: thanks again mate, I believe I should have put that "/images" after ten characters within the text of that row, would you know  how to code that?