# What is wrong with this bit of PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select rows that start with “<img” with an IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420971/how-to-select-rows-that-start-with-img-with-an-if-statement)

I am trying to add "/images" to the beginning of the row text_image when the text within begins with img. It is giving me an error.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result3 )) {
    echo "<div class='entry'>";
    $images = (substr($row['text_image']), 0, 3) == 'img') ? "/images" : "";
    echo $images . $row['text_image'];
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Maybe the error is that row['text_image'] is unidentified? Who knows...OP, please update.

Comment: It just isnt opening after in the browser after I added the substr line. The row has been identified. I was just wondering more whether there was something wrong within this code because I am getting a new error after inputting that substr line. I will try not using it if i have to. thanks for your time

Comment: Those errors mean something. Please provide them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra parenthesis. Try:

```
$images = (substr($row['text_image'], 0, 3) == 'img') ? "/images" : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result3 )) {
echo "<div class='entry'>";
$images = (
             substr($row['text_image'], 0, 3)

             == 'img') ? "/images" : "";
echo $images . $row['text_image'];
echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: What did you change (besides the spacing)?

Comment: both answers changed the extra parenthesis but the shorter one was more concise.